# Is there some way to create scalable block and save it into image with Cocoa?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to find some information about image creation and editing in OS X apps. Something like Sketch or Photoshop allows you to create a rectangle with any width and height. Is there some docs about how to create something looks like that in an OS X app?

I just wanna create scalable rectangle and save it into image.

P.S. And how to make it draggable with mouse?

Comment: You are using words like 'like,' 'something,' implying that you aren't even sure what you are looking for, opening the door to a wide range of possibilities.  I propose that this topic be closed.

Comment: If you've used PS or Sketch, you can understand what Im looking for. Need docs about how to create figures with free form and save it into png/svg/gif

Comment: Take a look at sample code [Sketch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Sketch/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot Willeke for the link, it's just what I was looking for!
[Sample code Sketch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Sketch/Introduction/Intro.html)

[image]